# DynamoDB query performance is low

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

First of all some specs:

- number of entries: 110k
- total size of table: 700MB
- number of columns per data set: can be up to 450
- data set size: can be up to 25kB
- read/write capacity: "on demand"

**Problem**: when trying to query for some rows by a column it takes easily up to 10 seconds or more.

The column we query by is an UUID column (index exists), not unique, used kind of like an external ID. So we say give me all records with that UUID and we expect up to ca. 1000 rows.

Even if I remove our application completely out of the equation (testing directly in the AWS management console) it makes no difference, still very poor performance (means also about 10 seconds or more).

So my question: do you have any ideas or concrete tips that I should check/test/adjust to improve the performance?

After request, here's the example code in PHP (reduced to relevant parts):
We use the official aws/aws-sdk-php package.

```php
do {
    // Marshal a native PHP array of data to a DynamoDB item.
    $transformedValue = $this->getDynamoArrayFromNativeArray(
        [':uuid' => $uuid]
    );

    $params = [
        'TableName'                 => 'our-table-name',
        'IndexName'                 => 'our-uuid-index',
        'KeyConditionExpression'    => 'our-uuid-column = :uuid',
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $transformedValue,
    ];

    if ($queryResult !== null) {
        $lastEvaluatedKey            = $queryResult['LastEvaluatedKey'];
        $params['ExclusiveStartKey'] = $lastEvaluatedKey;
    }

    $queryResult = $this->client->query($params);

    // (push results to some array)
} while ($queryResult['LastEvaluatedKey'] !== null);
```

Example data set:

```
{
  "_id": "82ee23ce-d7ff-11eb-bf92-0aa84964df0a",
  "_meta": {
    "creation_date": 1624877797,
    "uuid": "820025c0-d7ff-11eb-a5f4-0aa84964df0a"
  },
  "some_key.data.id": 63680,
  (couple of hundred more simple key => value pairs, nothing special, no huge values or anything like that)
```

Read capacity chart for the index in question:
[image]

Query latency chart:
[image]

Comment: Are you scanning the whole table?

Comment: No, we did that mistake in the past, now we explicitly only "query". Scanning took even multiple minutes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your DDB architecture and how you query the data? It'd be ideal if you can post the query code.

Comment: And please also quantify "poor performance".

Comment: I've added the example code. @Maurice the poor performance is about 10 seconds or more.

Comment: @jellycsc, what info can I provide regarding the architecture here, that would be of help? I'm not so experienced with DynamoDB hence the maybe silly question, sorry.

Comment: Can you add a few sample items from the index? Just to get an idea of what we're working with and how large they are.

Comment: @FrankDrebin How often do you iterate through the loop? Each response should be quite quick, but each response is limited to reading 1MB of data. Given the information you gave, your query result might be 6-8MB large, meaning you need 7-8 requests. Also you'd need to have enough RCUs available, even if you're in on-demand mode, you can hit limits on read capacity. How does the consumed read capacity chart look like?

Comment: @Maurice I've added the base structure of one sample item to my question. I think it has no special content to paste here. My concrete example has about 400 columns/keys and is about 25kB in byte size.

Comment: @peter thank you for your input, didn't know about that read limit. I've also checked the read capacity chart for our index. I've added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: You mention a couple hundred key-value pairs and hundreds of response items, is JSON-Encoding/Decoding maybe the bottleneck? You could also store the non-key attributes as a JSON-String and only decode them when necessary.

Comment: @Maurice you mean JSON en/decoding in our app? At this point I test directly in the AWS management console to keep our app out of it and the problem is the same.

Comment: There is a metric for query latency; what does that look like?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I've added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: Your query latency is under 100ms at peak. I'm not sure what the climbing rate indicates, perhaps a hot partition? Regardless, I don't see this as particularly slow. I'm guessing that much of the latency you are seeing is between AWS and you. How fast that is depends on a number of things that are out of the hands of AWS, like distance between you and the region you are running in, and the speed and bandwidth of your ISP.

Comment: Ok, so you would say that about 10 seconds per query in this example is reasonable? We're not doing anything tremendously wrong?